# WPF Combobox initial dictionary binding value not showing

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, dictionary, combobox

I have a wpf combobox bound to a property LogicalP of a class SInstance.  The ItemSource for the combobox is a dictionary that contains items of type LogicalP.

If I set LogicalP in SInstance to an initial state, the combobox text field shows empty.  If I select the pulldown all my dictionary values are there. When I change the selection LogicalP in SInstance gets updated correctly.  If I change Sinstance in C# the appropriate combobox value doesn't reflect the updated LogicalP from the pulldown.

I've set the binding mode to twoway with no luck.  Any thoughts?

My Xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="PList"
                    ObjectType="{x:Type src:MainWindow}"
                    MethodName="GetLogPList"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:SInstance}">
<Grid>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PList}}"
              DisplayMemberPath ="Value.Name" 
              SelectedValuePath="Value"
            SelectedValue="{Binding Path=LogicalP,Mode=TwoWay}">
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

My C#:

```
public Dictionary<string, LogicalPType> LogPList { get; private set; }
public Dictionary<string, LogicalPType> GetLogPList()
{
    return LogPList;
}

public class LogicalPType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public string M { get; set; }
}                  

public class SInstance : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private LogicalPType _LogicalP;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public LogicalPType LogicalP
    {
        get { return _LogicalP; }
        set
        {
            if (_LogicalP != value)
            {
                _LogicalP = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LogicalP");
            }
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not looking at the same source.
You need to have SInstance supply both the LogPList and LogicalP.

_LogicalP is not connected to LogPList

If you want to different objects to compare to equal then you need to override Equals.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're understanding the issue.  When I change the selection on the combobox, the underlying bound object (SInstance) gets updated, it stays blank.

However, when I change the property in SInstance the Combobox doesn't update to reflect the selected item.

Comment: Yes I do understand.  Show how you assign a value to LogicalP in C#.

Comment: Sorry by I didn't show the code where I've loaded the dictionary of LogPList on the main form load.  I did get to a solution to the problem which allows for the binding to go both ways.  I'll amend that to my original post.

Comment: I moved the method GetLogPList into the class SInstance as a property.  And that allowed the binding to be two-way.  I'm not quite sure why.

Comment: If this answers the question then indicate so with a check.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my working solution.  By moving the dictionary retrieval GetLogPList to the same class as that supplies the data (as suggested by Blam) I was able to get the binding to work both ways.  I changed binding to a list rather than a dictionary to simplify the combobox

Here's the updated Xaml showing the new ItemsSource binding and removal of the SelectedValuePath:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:SInstance}">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding GetLogPList}"
                  DisplayMemberPath ="Name" 
                SelectedValue="{Binding Path=LogicalP,Mode=TwoWay}">
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I then changed the dictionary LogPList to static so that it would be accessible to the class SInstance:

```
    public static Dictionary<string, LogicalPType> LogPList { get; private set; }
```

Finally, I moved GetLogPList to the class SInstance as a property.  Note again it's returning a list as opposed to a dictionary to make the Xaml a little simpler:

```
public class SInstance : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<LogicalPType> GetLogPList
    {
        get { return MainWindow.LogPList.Values.ToList(); }
        set { }
    }   

    private LogicalPType _LogicalP;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public LogicalPType LogicalP
    {
        get { return _LogicalP; }
        set
        {
            if (_LogicalP != value)
            {
                _LogicalP = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LogicalP");
            }
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    #endregion
}
```